# Can an object be in freefall if it is traveling upward?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

Can an object be in **freefall** if it is traveling upward? I'm thinking the answer is no?

Comment: Yes, it can. An object is in freefall if the only force acting upon it is gravity, this has nothing to do with its instantaneous velocity at exactly one point in time.

Comment: This isn't really a mathematics question, it's a question about terminology in physics. That said, if freefall is the state of having only gravity acting on it as a force (acceleration) then its velocity is independent, so it could be pointed up down left right whereever. The term is just about force

Comment: what is "up"? how is up defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the two comments, yes.  The definition of freefall is that the only force acting on the body is gravity, so if it is in an (approximate) vacuum and launched upwards by some force that terminates, it is in (approximate) freefall.  You can argue about the drag of the small atmosphere that exists and the solar radiation pressure, but those do not seem to be in the spirit of the question.